# what will happen when DynamoDB ttl is set as epoch timestamp in millisecond?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, ttl

As per this documentation https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ttl-dynamodb/ , the ttl must be set in seconds. but what will happen to the data if the ttl has been set incorrectly as ms while saving to dynamodb?

we have 5 months of data in dynamodb where ttl has been set incorrectly as 13 digit epoch timestamp(ms).
Any inputs is much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your data will not expire in a couple thousand years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a legit value you set, just very far in the future. If you can be super patient the problem will resolve itself in a few thousand years. ;)

Comment: Thanks, i was more worried that the data ttl got messed up and the data will be deleted before the expected ttl.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB has no built-in support for mass updates.

If I were in this situation, I would have written a script that i ran locally that queries the entire table and updates the TTL attribute to its correct value.

If the dataset is too large for that, I'd do it using lambdas and a queue instead (i.e. post the query results and the LastEvaluatedKey to the queue and process that accordingly in a lambda).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The table size is around 2TB in size, so it will be bit tricky. Will explore the second option that you have mentioned.